# Software development planning tool that allows hierarchical tasks

Tags: software-development, project-management, collaboration, planning

We are planning a new project that will involve four separate (but closely linked) web sites and an API, and are looking for a tool to help us manage all the ideas.

We would like something (preferably web-based) where we can set up a hierarchical structure, so ideas for each site can be kept together, but we can drill down into each site and see the main areas that the site covers, then drill down into each area and see the specific features in that area.

As we are still in the early planning stage, it's important to have a tool that allows discussions, so someone can suggest an idea, others can comment on it, and then when a specification has been settled, the discussion can be turned into a task.

We are currently using GitHub issues for this, but as it's not hierarchical, it's becoming very confusing trying to keep it organised. The discussion side of GitHub is excellent though.

I've been looking at infinitymaps.io, which has many of the features we would like, but I can't see that discussions would work well there.

Anyone able to recommend anything? Free would be great, but a modest price isn't an issue if it gets us something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends - lots of apps, mostly web apps, fit your criteria.

[Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) is possibly the most suitable one for software development:

- it works with the most common managements systems like scrum and kanban
- task hierarchies and relations are easily understandable
- it can generate bunch of different stats, charts and reports
- it integrates with mentioned GitHub and bunch of other 3rd party apps
- it's free up to 10 users as of now, for bigger teams you have to pay

Comment: Spent hours playing with various sites, and settled on Jira. Does what we need, free for up to 10 users and great community support. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Asana](https://asana.com/go/demo).  It supports

- multi-platforms
- multi-users
- tasks and subtasks
- and discussion between users
- due dates
- task or subtask assignment

For your use, there will be a charge.  I am not associated with it.  I just use it myself.

[image]